# jQgrid not refreshing records on formatoptions(edit)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#EmpGrid").jqGrid({
      url: "/Employee/GetRecords",
      datatype: "json",
      jsonReader: {
          root: "rows",
          page: "page",
          total: "total",
          records: "records",
          repeatitems: false,
          rownumbers: true,
          Id: "0"
      },
      editurl: "/Employee/EditEmployeeDetails",
      colNames: ["Actions", "Name", "City", "Address"],
      colModel: [
          {
              name: 'Id', index: 'Id', key: true, formatter: 'actions',
              formatoptions: {
                  keys: true,
                  editformbutton: true,
                  editOptions: { closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true },
             }
          },

          { name: "Name", key: true, editable: true, index: "Name", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "EditEmployee('", addParam: "');" } },
            @*{ name: "Name", editable: true, index: "Name", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employee")', idName:'id'} },*@

          { name: "City", index: "City", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text', editable: true },
          { name: "Address", index: "Address", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text', editable: true }
      ],
      rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      pager: "#pager",
      aftersavefunc: function () {
      },
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      gridview: true,
      rownumbers: true,
      height: "auto",
      loadonce: true,
      caption: "List of Employees",
      ignoreCase: true
  }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

My code is working fine. As I am new to Jqgrid , not aware of many things but on edit option provided in column , I am able to edit record in form and on submit `closeafteredit` is working fine, I also get edited data from server but `reloadaftersubmit` is not working.

I need help. please can anybody have idea? help me out please.